# What is the real address of `%fs:0xfffffffffffffff8`?

Tags: go, assembly, x86-64, bpf, ebpf

I want to trace the goid of go programs using `ebpf`.

After reading for some posts and blogs, I know that `%fs:0xfffffffffffffff8` points to the `g` struct of go and `mov %fs:0xfffffffffffffff8,%rcx` instruction always appear at the start of a go function.

Taking `main.main` as an example:

```
func main() {
 177341   458330:   64 48 8b 0c 25 f8 ff    mov    %fs:0xfffffffffffffff8,%rcx
 177342   458337:   ff ff
 177343   458339:   48 3b 61 10             cmp    0x10(%rcx),%rsp
 177344   45833d:   76 1a                   jbe    458359 <main.main+0x29>
 177345   45833f:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
 177346   458343:   48 89 2c 24             mov    %rbp,(%rsp)
 177347   458347:   48 8d 2c 24             lea    (%rsp),%rbp
 177348     myFunc()
 177349   45834b:   e8 10 00 00 00          callq  458360 <main.myFunc>
 177350 }
```

I also know the goid information is stored in the `g` struct of go. The value of fs register can be obtained via the `ctx` argument of `ebpf` function.

But I don't know what the real address of `%fs:0xfffffffffffffff8` because I am new to assembly language. Could anyone give me some hints?

If the value of fs register were 0x88, what is the value of `%fs:0xfffffffffffffff8`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a negative number, so it's one qword before the FS base.  You need the FS base address, which is *not* the selector value in the FS segment register that you could see with a debugger.

Your process probably made a system call to ask the OS to set it, or possibly used the [`wrfsbase`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/wrfsbase:wrgsbase) instruction at some point on systems that support it.

Note that at least outside of Go, Linux typically uses FS for thread-local storage.

(I'm not sure what the standard way to actually find the FS base is; it's obviously OS dependent to do that in user-space where `rdmsr` isn't available; FS and GS base are exposed as MSRs, so [OSes use that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497563/detail-about-msr-gs-base-in-linux-x86-64) instead of actually modifying a GDT or LDT entry.  [`rdfsbase`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rdfsbase:rdgsbase) needs to be enabled by the kernel setting a bit in CR4 on CPUs that support the FSGSBASE ISA extension, so you can't count on that working.)

@MargaretBloom suggests that user-space could trigger an invalid page fault; most OSes report the faulting virtual address back to user-space.  In Linux for example, SIGSEGV has the address.  (Or SIGBUS if it was non-canonical, IIRC.  i.e. not in the low or high 47 bits of virtual address space, but in the "hole" where the address isn't the sign-extension of the low 48.)

So you'd want to install signal handlers for those signals and try a load from an offset that (with 0 base) would be in the middle of kernel space, or something like that.  If for some reason that doesn't fault, increment the virtual address by 1TiB or something in a loop.  Normally no MMIO is mapped into user-space's virtual address space so there are no side effects for merely reading.

Comment: Could an induced page fault be used to find the base address of `fs`? I..e if `fs:x` faults with a reported virtual address of `y`

Comment: @MargaretBloom: You mean by catching SIGSEGV and SIGBUS (in case of non-canonical IIRC), because the kernel reports the virtual address back to user-space that way?  Yes, that could work!  I guess you'd want to load from some offset in the middle of what's normally kernel space.